# What is happen when virtual package depends/recommeds/suggest without real package depends/recommeds/suggest?

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg, lxde, aptitude

Recommends: xkb-data, x-terminal-emulator, pavucontrol | gnome-alsamixer

What is meaning for here the `x-terminal-emulator`?

I find [one link](https://lintian.debian.org/tags/virtual-package-depends-without-real-package-depends.html),but what should installed?

Is this `undefined behavior`?

For exmaple:

```
root@debian:/# cat /etc/os-release |grep ^PRETTY_NAME
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
root@debian:/# aptitude --disable-columns show lxpanel
Package: lxpanel                         
Version: 0.9.3-1
State: not installed
Priority: optional
Section: x11
Maintainer: Debian LXDE Maintainers <pkg-lxde-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Architecture: i386
Uncompressed Size: 753 k
Depends: libasound2 (>= 1.0.16), libatk1.0-0 (>= 1.12.4), libc6 (>= 2.7), libcairo2 (>= 1.2.4), libfm-gtk4 (>= 1.2.0), libfm4 (>= 1.2.0), libfontconfig1 (>= 2.11), libfreetype6
         (>= 2.2.1), libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0), libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.41.1), libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.24.0), libiw30 (>= 30~pre1), libkeybinder0 (>= 0.3.0), libmenu-cache3 (>= 0.5.0),
         libpango-1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0), libpangocairo-1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0), libpangoft2-1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0), libwnck22 (>= 2.30.7), libx11-6, libxml2 (>= 2.7.4), lxmenu-data, lxpanel-data
         (= 0.9.3-1), libfm-modules
Recommends: xkb-data, x-terminal-emulator, pavucontrol | gnome-alsamixer
Suggests: menu, firefox-esr | firefox | www-browser
Description: LXDE panel
 LXPanel is a GUI application for the Lightweight X11 Desktop Environment (LXDE). 

 It is derived from fbpanel and includes the following features: 

 * User-friendly application menu automatically generated from .desktop files on the system 
 * Launcher bar (small icons clicked to launch apps) 
 * Task bar supporting ICCCM/EWMH `urgency' hint (Pidgin IM windows can flash on new incoming messages) 
 * Run dialog (type a command to run, without opening a terminal) 
 * Net status icon plug-in (optional). 
 * Volume control plug-in (optional). 
 * Notification area (system tray). 
 * Digital clock. 
 * Keyboard LEDs plug-in (display caps/num locks). 
 * lxpanelctl: control lxpanel from other programs. For example, "lxpanelctl run" will show the Run dialog in lxpanel, and "lxpanelctl menu" will show the application menu. This
   is useful in combination with window manager key bindings.
Homepage: http://www.lxde.org/
Tags: hardware::input:mouse, interface::graphical, interface::x11, role::program, scope::utility, suite::TODO, uitoolkit::gtk, use::TODO, works-with::software:package,
      works-with::software:running, x11::applet, x11::application

root@debian:/#
```

Below-is-old-contents([found answer](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=133017&p=643753#p643753))

Why prompt me "termit" will installed,Why is not "lxterminal" will installed?

I expect "lxerminal" will installed because "lxde-core" first recommend "lxterminal" ,but why is "termit" will installed?

What I did and encountered:

If you need any more information can tell me ,thank

```
root@debian:~/debian_stretch# debootstrap stretch ./ http://ftp.cn.debian.org/debian/ >/dev/null
root@debian:~/debian_stretch# mount --bind /sys ./sys
root@debian:~/debian_stretch# mount --bind /proc ./proc
root@debian:~/debian_stretch# chroot ./
root@debian:/# apt update >/dev/null 2>&1
root@debian:/# echo Y |apt upgrade >/dev/null 2>&1
root@debian:/# echo n |apt install lxde-core 2>&1| grep -o termit
termit
termit
root@debian:/# echo n |apt install lxde-core 2>&1| grep -o lxterminal
root@debian:/# echo n |apt-get install lxde-core 2>&1| grep -o termit
termit
termit
root@debian:/# echo n |apt-get install lxde-core 2>&1| grep -o lxterminal
root@debian:/# apt-cache policy termit
termit:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.0-1+b1
  Version table:
     3.0-1+b1 500
        500 http://ftp.cn.debian.org/debian stretch/main i386 Packages
root@debian:/# apt-cache policy lxterminal
lxterminal:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.3.0-2
  Version table:
     0.3.0-2 500
        500 http://ftp.cn.debian.org/debian stretch/main i386 Packages
root@debian:/#
```

Again,if you need any more information can tell me ,thank

Comment: I made some edits to clarify the question. Please feel free to roll back me edits or change them if I got it wrong.

Comment: You really should do something about the broken locale.

Comment: What does `apt-cache policy termit` produce for you? Maybe also query for `lxterminal` and compare.

Comment: @tripleee I done you suggest,but fix locale maybe disturb the test result  by depends chain(I by install the locales package to fix it),so I will can't fix the locale on this question only.

Comment: @illiterate then `export LC_ALL=C` for the session before running commands whose output you want to show us.

Comment: @tripleee I done all of you suggest , very thank you,but I still not know why so depends(recommends) chain is happend.

Answer (score 2):

In the trivial case, a dependency on `A | B` will select A if neither is installed.

However, very commonly, dependency resolution is also affected by codependencies (if resolving other dependencies ends up pulling in B anyway, A doesn't need to be installed) and pinning (if a repository with B gets a higher pin, B will be selected).

Comment: But this question very odd,is B installed and B is a virtual package,I not understand why final `termit` is installed

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a package that satisfies the virtual package `x-terminal-emulator` installed, I think apt considers that dependency to be satisfied. And you probably already do. Off the top of my head, I'm not sure how to check that. Though `xterm`, `konsole`, `terminator` and many others provide `x-terminal-emulator`.

Comment: I'm sure non-existent any x-terminal-emulator before installing

Comment: Really? You don't have any `x-terminal-emulators` installed? So what do you type commands into?

Comment: Try running `aptitude search '?provides(x-terminal-emulator)'` and see if it outputs anything.

Comment: Yes, I'm very sure that ,I tried [a similar way](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/363357/why-isnt-lxterminal-installed-when-installing-lxde-core) as you said

Comment: If the system doesn't have X11, it won't have any X software at all. A server install or other basic console-only install would trivially exhibit this. On such systems, you log in on the hardware console, or over SSH.